# Using Hash+Range key for storing CloudWatch alarm in DynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I configured a CloudWatch alarm. I need this event to be captured and logged in a database for reporting purpose. Dynamo is chosen because of the low volume of incoming read/write.

What I need to capture:

- AWS account ID  (12345678912345)
- Datetime of the event
- Event ID

I have multiple AWS accounts, and I want to store them all in a single table (I could store them in separate table as well, but given the low volume not sure if that's really that useful).

So should I use Hash+Range?

```
Hash: <account_id>
Range: <datetime>
```

This way my understanding is DynamoDB will group/order based on the range.

My queries would only be:

- get all of the events for account_id / for all accounts
- get all of the events since x time for account_id / for all accounts

Is this a good design? Do I need a separate index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your query patterns, you approach looks correct.

- If you want data for only one `account_id`, do a `Query`. You can also supply a `KeyConditionExpression` on range-key to only get events that happened after given `timestamp`.
- If you want data for list of `account_id`s, run a `Scan`. (You *can't* do a `BatchGetItem`, because it needs both hash-key and range-key).

Comment: Thank you. It's useful to know which API to use.